# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send an email notification once a nested attribute form has been updated, but I keep bumping into this error, I think it because I am sending the email notification before council model has  updated the object in the database thus am getting a nil for Property.councils.email, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Property Mailer**

```
class PropertyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email(property, tenants, councils)
    @property = property
    @tenants = tenants
    @councils = property.councils
    mail(:to => property.councils.first.email, subject: 'Here are your property details')
  end
end
```

**property.rb**

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :council_histories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_histories, :reject_if => :send_email


  has_many :councils, through: :council_histories, :foreign_key => :council_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :councils

def send_email
    if council_histories.where(council_id_changed?)
      PropertyMailer.welcome_email(self, tenants, councils).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

## Update #

**'Property/Build Controller'** Nested controller, am using wicked wizard form gem, to build a multi-step form.

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

   steps :tenant, :meter, :council, :confirmed 

  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @tenants = @property.tenants.new(params[:tenant_id])
    @meter = @property.build_meter
    @property.council_histories.build do |council_history| 
    @council = council_history.build_council 
    end
    render_wizard
  end


  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    params[:property][:status] = step.to_s
    params[:property][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @property.update_attributes(params[:property])
    render_wizard @property
  end
end
```

**Form View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @property, url: wizard_path, :method => 'put' do |f|  %>


  <%= f.simple_fields_for :council_histories do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.input :property_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @property.id } %> 
      <%= builder.input :council_id, :collection => Council.all  %>

      <%= builder.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where are you populating the councils?

Comment: Councils is pre-defined, I am selecting a council for the property using the above simple form that I've updated on my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marek Lipka said, the property.councils most likely returns an empty hash, however that's only part of the story. I believe the issue is in your `Property` model, with this line:

```
has_many :council_histories
accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_histories, :reject_if => :send_email
                                                   ^^
                                                   This is the problem here
```

Your original hypothesis is correct, I believe are you attempting to send the email before the `:councils` relationship has a chance to populate. The `:reject_if` method is used to, as the name implies, throw out the data in certain circumstances (I never use it myself so can't think of any good examples, but I'm sure there are plenty). [Check here for more info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-One-to-many).

Do you absolutely need the email to be sent BEFORE the object is persisted? If not, maybe another alternative would to use one of the [ActiveRecord::Callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) methods, such as `after_commit`, like so:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :send_email
    # Remainder of model code....
```

Comment: Spot on mate thanks for the detailed answer, I tried using the after update callback beforehand and that didn't seemed to work, changed it to after commit, works perfectly thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `property.councils` call returns empty set.

Comment: I thought so, is there a way to call the current property.councils sorry am new to rails. Tried just councils, but I get same error.

Comment: @cyclopse87 I don't think we have enough information to answer that. You mentioned you believe the problem is due to the email being sent before the council model has updated, so we may need to see your controller code, so we can examine the sequence of events.

Comment: I have updated my question, with the nested controller, which is using a multi-step gem. Let me know if you need anything else?